# Django - Error: No module named grappelli

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-grappelli

I followed the [installation guide](http://django-grappelli.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html) for Grappelli:

Installed django-grappelli

```
$ pip install django-grappelli
```

Modified **settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
  'grappelli',
  'django.contrib.admin',
)
```

my **urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
  (r'^grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')),
)
```

And django tells me:

> Error: No module named grappelli

What did I forgot ?

**Edit**

```
$ pip install django-grappelli
```

> Requirement already satisfied: django-grappelli in /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages
>   Installing collected packages: django-grappelli
>   Successfully installed django-grappelli

```
$ pip freeze
```

> ...
>   django-grappelli==2.3.5
>   ...

Comment: I just followed the grappelli setup and everything ran. Can you try the shell and import grappelli to see if it works?

Comment: Are you running django in virtualenv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if grappelli in your PYTHONPATH. Run this in console:

```
$ python
>> import grappelli
```

If this throw ImportError you not installed this package.

Comment: It's indeed throwing the `ImportError`. Why `pip` didn't put it in the path ? How can I put it ?

Comment: @Glide: you can also run "pip freeze" to confirm you don't have grappelli installed at all or if you have other problems.

Comment: Your Django installation is most likely using a different Python (virtualenv? multiple versions?) than what pip used to install. Try doing `ls -al /usr/bin/python` - is that pointing to Python 2.6?

Comment: Following what @Martin said, make sure you are doing `python manage.py ...` and not just `manage.py ...` to make sure you are using the venv python.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same error. Problem was missing `__init__.py` file in package directory

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

The documentation does not mention that you need to add the following to urls.py:

```
import grappelli
```

Answer (score 1):

make sure you spell Grappelli with two 'P's and two 'L's - tis worked for me!

Comment: Same happened to me! I wrote the name wrong at `settings.py`!

Answer (score 0):

Try `pip3 install django-grappelli`
It helped me on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in Django (Ubuntu 16, PyCharm), try first:

```
sudo pip3 uninstall django-grappelli==2.13.4
```

after you should copy folder **grappelli** from:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/
```

to:

```
/your_project/venv/python3.5/site-packages/
```

after check in Python console:

```
>> import grappelli
```

Answer (score -2):

Make sure to do:`sudo pip install django-grappelli`. I didn't install it as root and that messed up the whole process.

Comment: This is a terrible suggestion. Learn about `virtualenv` so you don't need to worry about conflicts across various projects.